# Como puedo suspender un setInterval en acción?

Tags: html5, video, setinterval, contador, timeout

Cree un documento HTML5 para ver videos local. Trato de hacer similar a YouTube, al terminar el vídeo, muestra una sugerencia de vídeo similar y el siguiente vídeo a reproducir con `setInterval`. 
Mi problema aún, no logró detener el `setInterval` para volver a ver el vídeo.

```
  // AL FINAL DEL VIDEO
  var mas = $('.relacionados');
  var fin = $('video');
  var counter=10;

  $("video").on("ended", function() { 
   mas.show();

  //Siguiente vídeo
  setTimeout (function() {
  window.location.href = 'yoVideos.html';  
  },10000);
  //Cuenta regresiva
  var id = setInterval(function(){ 
  if(counter==0) clearInterval(id); 
  else { 
  counter=counter-1; 
  document.querySelector('.counter').innerHTML=counter;  
  } }, 1000);

  });

  // CANCELAR SIGUIENTE VIDEO
  function cancelar() {
    clearTimeout(fin);
    mas.toggle();
    document.getElementById("cancelar"); 
  }

  <div class="detalles">
    <span>Siguente vídeo:</span>
      <h3>Título del siguiente vídeo</h3>   
    <span>En: <b class="counter">10</b>s
      <span class="cancelar" onclick="cancelar()">Cancelar</span>
    </span>     
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var counter = 5;

var id = setInterval(function(){
if(counter == 0){
clearInterval(id);
document.
}
document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = counter;

counter--;

},1000);
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>
```

Puedes poner el código del setTimeout dentro del setInterval ya que ambos terminan al mismo tiempo:

```
var id = setInterval(function(){ 
  if(counter==0) {
    clearInterval(id);
    window.location.href = 'yoVideos.html'; 
  }
  else { 
   counter=counter-1; 
   document.querySelector('.counter').innerHTML=counter;  
  }
 }, 1000);
```

Y en la función `cancelar()` cancelas el setInterval:

```
function cancelar() {
    clearInterval(id);
    mas.toggle();
    document.getElementById("cancelar"); 
  }
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var counter = 5;

var id = setInterval(function(){
if(counter == 0){
clearInterval(id);
//document.location.href="";
}
document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = counter;

counter--;

},1000);

function cancelar(){

clearInterval(id);

}
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>

<button onclick="cancelar()">cancelar</button>
```

Comment: Al combinar setTimeout con setInterval, el contador (cuenta regresiva) no me funciona.

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo en la respuesta. Quité el setTimeout y pasé el código al setInterval

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda